# Объединить несколько COM портов с помощью com0com и hub4com

Tags: сеть

Нужно объединить COM10 с COM11, COM12... COM18 для работы в программе N.

Если создаю пару в com0com, например COM10 и COM11 то программа N это видит. Или COM10 с COM14 тоже все ок.

Пробовал создавать пары COM10-CNCB0, COM11-CNCB1, COM12-CNCB2 и с помощью hub4com объединять
`hub4com --route=All:All \\.\CNCB0 \\.\CNCB1 \\.\CNCB2` и это не сработало.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: а сколько com портов одновременно будет работать?

Comment: Хм. Думаю максимум одновременно 1 пара. Т.е. 10 отправляет на 11, потом 10ый отправляет на 12 и т.д.

Comment: Я использовал программу Virtual COM Port Driver от Eltima и там можно на вкладке Merge все объединить и оно работает. Но программа платная и через 15 дней все умерло. Подсказали бесплатный вариант с com0com в связке с hub4com. Но что-то не срастается